# Assign route to a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hey guys i need to implement a button that will have a route assigned, i am writing on top of the existed code so I am a bit lost, there is a private route component wrapped in Switch component. How to i assign a route to my buttons onClick

```
<Switch>

   <PrivateRoute exact path="/settings" component={Settings}/>
   <PrivateRoute exact path="/admin" component={AdminButton}/>
```

The Private Route consist of the following

```
@inject('auth')
@observer
class PrivateRoute extends Component {

  render() {
    const {auth, component, ...rest} = this.props;
    const RouteComponent = component;
    const {authenticated, authenticating} = auth;
    return (
       <Route
          {...rest}
          render={props =>
             (authenticated || authenticating) ? (
                <RouteComponent {...props} />
             ) : (
                <Redirect to="/login" />
             )
          }
       />
```

AdminButton component that needs to receive something to onClick i guess

```
export default class AdminButton extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <QuestionButtonStyled onclick={}>Admin Panel</QuestionButtonStyled>
    }
}
```

App.jsx

```
 <DashboardLayout>
                            {this.props.auth.authenticated && <EpMenu/> }
                            <div style={{marginTop: '20px'}}>
                                <Switch>
                                    <Route exact path="/login/:token?" component={LoginPage}/>
                                    <PrivateRoute exact path="/welcome" component={Welcome}/>
                                    <PrivateRoute exact path="/monthly-payslip" component={MonthlyPayslip}/>
                                    <PrivateRoute exact path="/yearly-tax-overview" component={YearlyTaxStatementOverview}/>
                                    <PrivateRoute exact path="/social-security-documents" component={SocialSecurityDocuments}/>
                                    <PrivateRoute exact path="/central-information-documents" component={CentralDocuments}/>
                                    <PrivateRoute exact path="/settings" component={Settings}/>
                                    <PrivateRoute exact path="/admin" component={AdminButton}/>
                                    <Redirect from="/*" to="/login"/>
                                </Switch>
                            </div>
                        </DashboardLayout>
```

Comment: What is the onClick supposed to do?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri hey thank you for your time, just to open change the route to another component

Comment: You could use `<Link as={QuestionButtonStyled}>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to change the route on `onClick` event, you can make use of `history` from props and pass on the new path like

```
export default class AdminButton extends React.Component {
    handleClick=() => {
       this.props.history.push('/settings');
    }
    render() {
        return <QuestionButtonStyled onClick={this.handleClick}>Admin Panel</QuestionButtonStyled>
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey man  sadly i get Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: are you using the arrow function for defining handleClick

Comment: Yes i do use arrow function :(

Comment: Its interesting, because I do see you passing props to AdminButton component from PrivateRoute

Comment: I submitted whats inside App file , could you kindly have a look

Comment: what you have seems correct. Can you just log `this.props` and see what all you get

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214846/discussion-between-artjom-prozorov-and-shubham-khatri).